# How to shuffle pairs

Tags: java, list, arraylist, generator, shuffle

How to shuffle the elements in the pairs?
The program below, generate all possible pairs and later shuffle the pairs.
e.g. possible pairs before shuffle is `ab,ac,ae,af`..etc shuffled to `ac,ae,af,ab`...etc

How to make it not only shuffled in pairs but within the elements in the pair itself?
e.g. instead of `ab, ac,` how can I make `ba, ac` ?

```
String[] pictureFile   = {"a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg","d.jpg","e.jpg","f.jpg","g.jpg"};
    List <String>  pic1= Arrays.asList(pictureFile);
    ...
ListGenerator pic2= new ListGenerator(pic1);

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> pic2= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();


public class ListGenerator {
    public ListGenerator(List<String> pic1) {
     int size = pic1.size();

     // create a list of all possible combinations
     for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        for(int j = (i+1) ; j < size ; j++) {
           ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           temp.add(i);
           temp.add(j);
              pic2.add(temp);
            }
        }
      Collections.shuffle(pic2);
    }

    //This method return the shuffled list
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getList()  {
         return pic2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to shuffle the `temp` list before you add it to `pic2`. Here's the fixed code (note that I turned the `pic2` variable into a field of the `ListGenerator` class and renamed it to `result`)

```
  String[] pictureFile   = {"a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg","d.jpg","e.jpg","f.jpg","g.jpg"};
  List <String>  pic1= Arrays.asList(pictureFile);
      ...
  ListGenerator pic2= new ListGenerator(pic1);

  public class ListGenerator {

     ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

     public ListGenerator(List<String> pic1) {
        int size = pic1.size();

        // create a list of all possible combinations
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
           for(int j = (i+1) ; j < size ; j++) {
              ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
              temp.add(i);
              temp.add(j);

              Collections.shuffle(temp);
              result.add(temp);
           }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(result);
     }

     //This method return the shuffled list
     public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getList()  {
        return result;
     }
  }
```

However this is just the first step towards a solution. Currently, each pair will contain integers in the range `[0..size-1]` so your pairs look like this: `<0,3>`, `<1,2>`, etc. What you probably want is to get a pairs that are two-letter String such as: `"ab", "dc"`, etc. In this version I renamed `getList()` to `getPairs()` which convey its meaning better. Also, I made the constructor of `ListGenerator` accept an array of characters so you just need to call it with your desired characters, as follows:

```
  List<String> pairs = new ListGenerator('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g').getPairs();
```

And here is `ListGenerator` it self:

```
  public class ListGenerator {

     ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

     public ListGenerator(char...  letters) {
        int size = letters.length;

        // create a list of all possible combinations
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
           for(int j = (i+1) ; j < size ; j++) {
              ArrayList<Character> temp = new ArrayList<Character>();
              temp.add(letters[i]);
              temp.add(letters[j]);

              Collections.shuffle(temp);
              result.add("" + temp[0] + temp[1]);
           }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(result);
     }

     //This method return the shuffled list
     public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getPairs()  {
        return result;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have these objects:

```
Red dress
Blue shirt
Pink panties
```

And you want to shuffle both the colors and the articles of clothings to get things like:

```
Pink shirt
Blue panties
... etc
```

How do you do it?

It's simple, really: just shuffle the list of colors and articles of clothings separately, and then join them again.

```
Red, Blue, Pink            -->  Pink, Blue, Red
dress, shirt, panties      -->  shirt, panties, dress
                               ------------------------ pair
                                Pink shirt
                                Blue panties
                                Red dress
```